# Servlet jsp null pointer exception

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, nullpointerexception, requestdispatcher

Basically I have this function that allows people to search for other user based on their usernames. You type into the textbox id="search" and it will look for users with that username/similar username:

```
<form name="searchForm" action="searchUser"  method="post">
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search.." />
<input type="submit" id="searchButton" name="searchButton" value="Search!" onclick="searchUsers()"/>
</form>
```

This is the servlet SearchUserServlet that maps to the action searchUser.The static method searchUser(string) returns an arraylist of user objects. I am trying to pass this arraylist to QuickMatchResult.jsp:

```
public class SearchUserServlet extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

        try {

            String name=request.getParameter("search");
       ArrayList<User> userList=  User.searchUser(name);



            RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("/QuickMatchResult.jsp");
            request.getSession().setAttribute("userList",userList);
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is the QuickMatchResult.jsp where it is forwarded. I'm trying to show all the usernames of the user objects in the arraylist:

```
<table id="searchResults">
<%      ArrayList<User> userList= new ArrayList<User>();
userList=(ArrayList<User>)request.getAttribute("userList");
for (int i=0; i<userList.size();i++){
User user=userList.get(i);
%>
<tr>
<td><%=user.getUserName()%></td>    
</tr>
<%

}
%>
</table>
```

However when I try to run this, I get a null pointer exception. Any idea why?

Comment: check if userList from request is null

Comment: Read the userlist in jsp from session instead of request as you are setting the userlist in session

Answer (score 0):

You have set your attribute in the session and not in request. Use

```
request.setAttribute("userList", userList);
```

or if you want to use session, then retrieve the session attribute in JSP.

```
session.getAttribute("userList");
```

We get `NullPointerException` when we are trying to call a method on the object reference which does not refer to object. i.e. `null`.

In your case, you are trying to retrieve an attribute named `userList` from the `request` object, but there is no any attribute as such in `request`. If `getAttribute` does not find the attribute, it returns `null`

Comment: Thanks mate! I had it like that initially but it didn't work.

Comment: i think he is setting it in session itself

Comment: @zerocool can you provide details about the problem? at which line you are getting NullPointerException and on what variable? I need more information

Comment: @zerocool sorry the message was meant for .Blaiz, can you provide full stacktrace? it would help us help you

Comment: Haha, thats what i was wondering :) @Blaiz check my post try it and if still doesnt work, put the stacktrace as Prasad is asking

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the userList in sesion object and trying to retrieve it from request object. Get this list from session not from the request.Below should help

```
userList=(ArrayList<User>)session.getAttribute("userList");
```